# Not understanding the intuition behind spanning sets

Tags: linear-algebra

So there was an example in my textbook that explained how to show one spanning set is equal to another. However, while I do understand the algebra, I'm not sure why they are allowed to do certain things, or why they do them.

The example:

If x and y are in $R^{n}$ show that span{x, y} = span{x+y, x-y}

Since both x + y and x - y are in span{x, y}, Theorem 1 gives span{x + y, x - y} ⊆ span{x, y}.

But $x = {1\over 2}(x+y) + {1\over 2}(x-y)$ and $y = {1\over 2}(x+y) - {1\over 2}(x-y)$ are both in span{x + y, x - y}, so span{x, y} ⊆ span{x + y, x - y} again by Theorem 1. Thus span{x, y} = span{x + y, x - y}, as desired.

Why did they want to show that $x = {1\over 2}(x+y) + {1\over 2}(x-y)$? I always thought that to show a vector is in a spanning set, it has to be written as a linear combination of the vectors in the set. Also, why are x + y and x - y in the span{x, y}?

Comment: are you sure you understand the definition of span? I think you should go back there and try to solve your question on your own.

Comment: If you don’t know why $x+y$ and $x-y$ are in the span of $x$ and $y$ then you need to go back and reread the definition of span

Answer (score 1):

Since we can express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $x+y$ and $x-y$, we can represent any linear combination of $x$ and $y$ as a linear combination of $x+y$ and $x-y$. Therefore, every element of the span of $\{x,y\}$ is in the span of $\{x+y,x-y\}$.

For example: suppose a vector $v\in\mathrm{span}\{x,y\}$. Then $v=c_1x+c_2y$ for some $c_1,\,c_2$. Then:

$$v=c_1x+c_2y=c_1\left(\frac12 (x+y) + \frac12 (x-y)\right) + c_2\left(\frac12 (x+y)-\frac12 (x-y)\right)=
\left(\frac12 c_1 + \frac12 c_2\right)(x+y)+\left(\frac12 c_1 - \frac12 c_2\right)(x-y)$$

Answer (score 0):

It may help to look at this from another perspective.

Consider the span of $w$ and $z$ - it certainly contains all the vectors in the span of $\frac {w+z}2, \frac {w-z}2$ (we are allowed to divide by $2$) because elements in this span are clearly linear combinations of $w$ and $z$.

Now define $w=x+y$ and $z=x-y$ (what we did before just assumed they were vectors in general - now we make them specific vectors we have chosen). We find that the span of $w, z$ includes the span of $x, y$.

We had previously that the span of $x,y$ includes the span of $w, z$.

So the two spans must be equal.

What we have here is an invertible transformation between one spanning set and another.